# Left Join Query issue of displaying duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `person` and `courses_by_instructors`.  I am executing an sql query but I am getting duplicate values for the desired result. I am fetching from `person` table all those with `instructor_roles = 1` that are currently teaching a `course`.  What suggestions in regards to the query or table could be made? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e18b1/1)

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.instructor_role, IFNULL(lj.company_id, 0) as  company_id, lj.person_id, lj.course_name
FROM person as p
LEFT JOIN courses_by_instructors as lj
      ON (lj.person_id = p.person_id AND lj.company_id = 7 )
WHERE instructor_role = 1
ORDER BY person_name
```

Desired Result:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| person_id | instructor_name | course_name | company_id |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|       154 | James Newton    |             |            |
|       154 | James Newton    |             |            |
|       478 | Tina Turner     |             |            |
|       258 | James Fuller    |             |            |
|       717 | Michael Jordan  | Shoe Biz    |          7 |
|       717 | Michael Jordan  | Basketball  |          7 |
|       964 | Steve Johnson   |             |            |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Current:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
| person_id | instructor_name | course_name | company_id |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|       154 | James Newton    |             |            |
|       154 | James Newton    |             |            |
|       478 | Tina Turner     |             |            |
|       258 | James Fuller    |             |            |
|       717 | Michael Jordan  | Shoe Biz    |          7 |
|       717 | Michael Jordan  | Basketball  |          7 |
|       717 | Michael Jordan  | Shoe Biz    |          7 |
|       717 | Michael Jordan  | Basketball  |          7 |
|       964 | Steve Johnson   |             |            |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: add `p.company_id as notdupe` to your select list and you cann see they are not dupe results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.instructor_role, IFNULL(lj.company_id, 0) as  company_id, lj.person_id, lj.course_name
FROM person as p
LEFT JOIN courses_by_instructors as lj
      ON (lj.person_id = p.person_id AND lj.company_id = 7 )
WHERE instructor_role = 1
GROUP BY p.person_id,lj.course_name
ORDER BY person_name
```

It will give you what you need.

See output in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e18b1/60)

Comment: This exactly what I needed! `GROUP BY p.person_id,lj.course_name` made difference I think.

Answer (score 1):

The query is ok but the problem is in your model.
I would say the person table should be created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person
    (
     company_id int, 
     person_id int, 
     person_name varchar(30),
     instructor_role tinyint,
     staff_role tinyint,
     CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON_ID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (person_id), 
    );
```

Having the person ID as the primary key. And the courses_by_instructors table should be created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE courses_by_instructors
    (
     company_id int, 
     person_id int, 
     course_id int,
     course_name varchar(30),
     CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_ID FOREIGN KEY (person_id) 
        REFERENCES person(person_id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

Having a foreign key referencing the person ID.

Please note that I'm using SQL Server so you may need to tweak the syntax a little bit.

Comment: ...can you elaborate, how does it solve the problem of duplicate records appearing in the resultset?

Comment: @DipenduPaul: I think the problem is in how the tables are defined. If you check that link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e18b1/1 you will notice that the person table have records with the same person ID, instructor role, and staff role which does not make sense IMHO

Comment: Now I can see...the design is not normalized.. but then company id shouldn't be part of Person table, if there is N:N relation between Person and Company, then Company should go into some other table and for maintaining the N:N relation an another table can be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.instructor_role, IFNULL(lj.company_id, 0) as  company_id, lj.person_id, lj.course_name
FROM person as p
LEFT JOIN courses_by_instructors as lj
  ON (lj.person_id = p.person_id AND lj.company_id = p.company_id )
WHERE instructor_role = 1
ORDER BY person_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get what you asked:

```
SELECT * from person
left join (select * from courses_by_instructors group by company_id) as mytable on mytable.person_id = person.person_id
where instructor_role = 1
order by person.person_name
```

However, you don't have duplicates in your initial query, since `company_id` will be different

Answer (score 0):

It can achieved by DISTINCT in SELECT statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.person_id, p.person_name, p.instructor_role, IFNULL(lj.company_id, 0) as  company_id, lj.person_id, lj.course_name
FROM person as p
LEFT JOIN courses_by_instructors as lj
      ON (lj.person_id = p.person_id AND lj.company_id = 7 )
WHERE instructor_role = 1
ORDER BY person_name
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e18b1/62)